# Failed to connect to Firebase from Android Studio Assistant

Tags: firebase, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to connect to Firebase from Android Studio Assistance but getting following error despite having internet connection.

[image]

Comment: A note for future developers facing this issue for the first time: Please refer the last line of the error message... In fact, I tried connecting again and a message popped up saying "This app is already connected to a project. Click the _sync_ button to upgrade configuration information."

Comment: Duplicate issue. Please refer here for your solution which worked for me. You can give a try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433391/5882307

Answer (score 5):

This Error occurs when you reach total number of projects limit on FireBase which FireBase allow you to can create per FireBase account. Then FireBase not Allow you to create any more project through Android Studio. 
In this case you can only connect with existing projects through Android Studio.

Share to improve...

Comment: I felt for the first time that I was fooled by google.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way to get around this is to create (or upgrade your project to enable Firebase) in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) first; then connect your app through the Android Studio tool again.

This is a generic failure message so to help us investigate it would be great if you could provide the detailed error message from the Studio log. You can find this by going to '**Help** > **Show Log ...**'.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was with the account I was signed in firebase. I was signed in with my university account (which is not gmail, but uses gmail's services). After signing in with my 'gamil.com' account, the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Just sign out your gmail account from Android Studio and then re-sign in again. After this, try again connecting to the firebase. It should connect!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed below steps and it worked.

Android SDK Manager > Tools > Options > [select] Force https://...

[image]

Comment: cant able to find this option in Studio 2.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had this message as well.  However, when I went to the Firebase console I noticed that one of my project variants got uploaded.  So, I ignored the error message and continued connecting to Firebase.  Every time I did this it uploaded one of my variants.  When all of my variants were uploaded, the error message went away.

Answer (score 0):

simply increase the project quota from firebase....it's free
i was facing this issue for very long time but now issue is resolved. i think android studio should return the proper message.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are giving a new point of view, try to explain a little bit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. I tried everything. I have searched everything on google but did not got anything but finally I got a solution for this.
Firstly go and simply update your android studio and plugin. After updating your android studio to latest version, every problem will get sort.

After doing the above step, if you are still facing the same issue then check, if you have already made three projects on google cloud platform i.e. firebase.
If you have already made three then contact google to increase your free project quota on firebase.
To do so, fill the below form, they will approve your request.
form link - https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase

When google will approve your request then your issue should get resolved

Answer (score 0):

Change your Android studio **http and proxy** settings to no proxy and rebuild your project.
This one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your android studio. By doing this my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the FireBase Plugin in SDK Manager