# Getting errors trying to add Firebase project from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add Firebase to my project via Android Studio by going to Tools > Firebase > authentication > Email and Password Authentication > Connect to Firebase. A dialog pops up, I choose create new Firebase Project and I get the following error, even though I have a fully working internet connection:

> Firebase: Connect to Firebase failed. Please check your internet connection 
>      and try again. If errors persist, you can connect manually at 
>      https://console.firebase.google.com Project creation was attempted so an online project may exist online and registered to your account despite this failure message.

It's much easier setting it up this way rather than doing it manually, so I would like to solve the issue.

EDIT:

The problem turned out to be that I had reached the limit for adding new projects. To solve this issue, you have to delete some apps, link the new project to an existing one, or request for additional projects creation from the Firebase team.

Comment: but you have to write your steps and what did you do to now what is the problem and help you.

Comment: You have to create project on Firebase and create platform (Android/IOS), and add the google_services.json file to the project src. did you do it ?

Comment: @AmjadOmari Yeah I can do it. I just want to do it the easy why by using the Firebase tool withing Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com
2. Login to your account
3. Create a new project as per your requirements
4. Follow this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 14):

**It's simple.**

> You all have to just Sign-out and then Sign-in again.

1. [image: Step 1]
2. [image: Step 2]

Problem fixed for me at least. You can try it.

Answer (score 2):

**go to android studio -> settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings**

1. Check Auto Detect Proxy Setting. (Select the option)
2. check Connection with error website

   For Ex. https://console.firebase.google.com

Apply Changes. and try again without Restarting or with restarting your android studio

Answer (score 2):

For me it is solved after updating firebase service plugin.

Go to Settings > Plugins > Firebase Services.
Make sure it is updated and enabled

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem just update your Android studio and plugins by going > Settings >Updates >Check for update

**after Updating Restart your pc**

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened because i have exhausted my project number limit,so I have requested for extension of project limit and after that every thing worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Simply add google play service then update the firebase plugins and restart android studio. You will connect without an issue. 14.8.2021.

Answer (score -2):

You should check other plugins.

Here is an example of what was the problem in my case. The first lines in application `build.gradle` are:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
...
```

I have missed the second line and after adding it, the same issue was resolved for me.

Comment: What if we don't have Fabric?

Comment: This was just one example that resolved a similar situation in my case.