# Connect to Firebase Failed

Tags: android, android-studio

**Hello, my app was up and running on firebase yesterday morning, but as of today, I can't seem to connect to firebase and I'm getting the following error message:**
"Firebase: Connect to Firebase failed. Please check your internet connection and try again. If errors persist, you can connect manually at https://console.firebase.google.com". I've tried connecting it manually and it didn't work, I also tried using another internet connection and nothing happened.
I'm not new to Android or Firebase, I've worked on several firebase projects before and everything went well.
If there's a new update with new requirements please let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675320/failed-to-connect-to-firebase-from-android-studio-assistant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try again once today because i also face similar problem but toady it get resolved

Comment: Yes it worked, I guess it was just an issue from the firebase servers then.